# Why would a US company tell their employees that they will pay for a union?

Tags: united-states, unions

I recently read about [a union effort in Amazon](https://www.vice.com/en/article/3anw9k/amazon-sends-vote-no-instructions-to-unionizing-employees-tells-them-to-use-new-mailbox) and a photo of an Amazon flyer was mentioning that accepting a union at Amazon means paying for it:

[image]

*([source](https://www.vice.com/en/article/3anw9k/amazon-sends-vote-no-instructions-to-unionizing-employees-tells-them-to-use-new-mailbox))*

I am French and do not know how unions work in the US, so apologies if the question is obvious: **are all employees of a company automatically paying for a union once there is one in the company?**

By "paying", I mean "having an entry on the payslip with "union fees"".

I can imagine that there are some indirect payments possible (the company must co-pay for the union, and this may ultimately mean that the salaries are lower (this is an extreme example)), or that some employees want to join the union (and pay their fees).

The flyer seems to suggest however that once a union is formed, everyone must pay for it. Is that correct?

Comment: I wonder how much money was paid to print and distribute those flyers.

Comment: @IDDQD - almost nothing.  At scales of 100,000 flyers, it's less than a cent to literally print flyers.  Note that the budget for - say - chairs at Amazon would be on the order of $100 /employee annually.

Comment: The flyer appears to be part of a campaign to prevent the unionization effort, by persuading employees to vote against it so they can save the money on the dues (vs spending it on health insurance etc which a union could possibly to negotiate). This type of PR battle is a standard procedure in the US.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Employees pay something called "union dues" in the United States**

Unions are not free to run. They hire benefit administrators. They sometimes manage pensions. They definitely need to hire negotiators. They pay for this by charging their members a fee.

> are all employees of a company automatically paying for a union once there is one in the company?

All employees in the bargaining unit, which is nearly always smaller than the number of employees in the company and in this case much smaller. Bargaining units might form around a location, a particular skillset, or even job function.

> By "paying", I mean "having an entry on the payslip with "union fees"".

Quite often. The unions often prefer to deduct dues directly from paycheques.

> The flyer seems to suggest however that once a union is formed, everyone must pay for it. Is that correct?

Depends on the particular laws of the state. In some states, if a majority vote for a union, everyone must pay. In "right-to-work" states, official membership in the union is optional and so is paying union dues.  So the union would still exist, it is just that a large number of people could opt-out of being members.

Comment: Your summary of how unions function in "right-to-work" states is a little misleading. Even in right-to-work states, employers can (depending on state law) enter into agreements with unions that make *getting and keeping a job contingent on the worker making agency fee payments to the union* even if workers are not required to be part of the union. https://www.justia.com/employment/unions/right-to-work-and-union-dues/

Comment: *Unions are not free to run. (...) They pay for this by charging their members a fee.* Thanks for that information. It is yet another example of differences between US and EU. Over here unions will be subsidized by the state, region, company where they are present, and finally the fees of members. But once they are in a company, they negotiate for all the employees, affiliated or not.

Comment: Example: The teachers in a state are typically county employees.  The county has a teacher's union for that school district.  You don't have to join the teacher's union, but in order to receive a union representative, you must have opted into joining the union.  However, you get the benefits of their being a teacher's union, you also get the negatives depending how you look at it.  To further complex this example, in some states you have to join the union, in others you don't have to join.  Even if you are not a member, the union still will represent you, and negotiate your pay and benefits.

Comment: In other words... now Both Amazon *AND* the Union Administrators get rich off the labor of underpaid Amazon employees. Seems way better to me!

Comment: *In "right-to-work" states, official membership in the union is optional and so is paying union dues. So the union would still exist, it is just that a large number of people could opt-out of being members.* This often works out to being mandatory or you're not hired or get fired. The unions for many grocery stores are cutthroat...

Comment: @SnakeDoc Please define: "get rich".

Comment: @WoJ Unions were never subsidized by the state in the UK, even before Brexit. In fact he opposite was true. Unions donate a large proportion of the funding to the Labour Party, and therefore expect a lot of political control over it in return. For example the unions which are formally "affiliated" elect around 30% of the membership of the Labour Party's executive committee. Many "non-affiliated" unions take a political levy from members in addition to their membership dues (though members can opt out) and use it for political funding.

Comment: Per SCOTUS, compelled contributions to a labor union infringe on first amendment free speech if workers are government workers

Answer (score 7):

> The flyer seems to suggest however that once a union is formed, everyone must pay for it. Is that correct?

Yes. They're called [union dues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_dues). Quoting wikipedia (emphasis mine):

> Union dues are a regular payment of money made by members of unions. Dues are the cost of membership; they are used to fund the various activities which the union engages in. **Nearly all unions require their members to pay dues.**

Unions typically benefit the employee much more so than the employer so it's unlikely the employer would voluntarily pay for it out of their own pocket.

Unions claim that members often have higher salaries to justify those dues. Like sure, you may be $500 / year to the union but, in theory, your salary might be, say, 30% more, because of your membership in the union, so if that 30% is $30,000 then $500 in union dues is a pittance compared to that. At least so the theory goes.

Comment: *Unions claim that members often have higher salaries to justify those dues* Does that mean that a union works only for its members? In other words - whatever they negotiate benefits only their members, not all employees?

Comment: "everyone must pay for it." was the main point of the question. so it rather be a 'NO' as only the members have to pay

Comment: @WoJ It varies... but setting the law such that union negotiation benefits all workers but not all must pay is a classic first move by union-busters in taking down the union altogether.  Once the union is no longer permitted to negotiate only for its own members, it's generally pretty much doomed.

Comment: @FooTheBar Often, union shops do not permit non-union workers at all.

Comment: @BenBarden: I see that unions in the US are **vastly** different from the ones we have in France (and broadly - in the EU). In France, a union negotiates for all the employees, whether they are members or not. You can be a member and it helps if you want to be represented directly (you can go to HR with a union delegate for instance), but even in that case, it is not compulsory. The union has zero impact on hiring and there are usually several unions in one company - so you never know (even within a union) if someone is unionized or not (except for the delegates of course)

Comment: @WoJ Unions in America vary from industry to industry, and state to state.  Many unions are local, but can be affiliated with others.  Sometimes they work at cross purposes, and there can be multiple unions at the same shop.

Add to that the fact that different states have different rules and laws governing both unions and union contracts.  In some, union membership can be mandatory, in others, it can be optional, but you still have to pay for the collective bargaining, which is broken out of the standard dues, so if the membership is 25/paycheck, a non member may still have to pay 15.

Comment: @BenBarden it can get very complex.  Some shops have multiple unions, some have mandatory membership, others have union and non-union employment where no fees are collected from non-union, others have contracts where a non-union member must still pay for collective bargaining.  So, yeah, it gets complicated.

Comment: @FooTheBar - _"everyone must pay for it." was the main point of the question. so it rather be a 'NO' as only the members have to pay_. That goes without saying. Other people who don't need to pay for union dues include people who aren't employed by Amazon. I should think that's so obvious, however, that that fact need not be stated.

Comment: @neubert: well it seems that this is not the case (there are cases where you must pay despite not being a union member, just by the fact that you work there)

Comment: @WoJ - incredibly different, right ?!

Comment: @WoJ - It depends on the state.  There are states that have written laws in their state constitution promote the concept of a union.  In other states unions might still exist.  There is also a federal employee work force.  You often don't have to be a member in order of that either unless you live in a state that requires it.

Comment: There are also different types of unions. Some run apprenticeship programs training new members and set standards of craftmanship. Others simply negotiate wages and benefits for their members.